# como pegar um valor e fazer post dele em um modal?

Tags: javascript, post, modal

meu html está assim:

```
<a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="login">logar</a>
```

eu preciso de um php ou javascript que faça um post ou um onclick que mande a o valor  "data-id='login'" para um get dentro do modal .....no modal vai ter um get pra pegar o valor e fazer um

```
document.getElementById("login").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

na div `"#login"` dentro do modal

---

tipo assim:

```
      <a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="post" value="var-1">logar1</a>
      <a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="post" value="var-2">logar2</a>
```

quando clicado ele ativa esse modal aqui:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="modal-formlogin">
   <?php
   $variable = $_GET["aqui o recebe o valor de value"];
   echo $variable;
   ?>
   </div>
```

eu acredito que eu deva usar um javascript jah que não muda de página... o modal fica na mesma página, ele está oculto mas quando ativa ele aparece e recebe o valor

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"para um get dentro do modal"_?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, Funciona perfeitamente:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var variavel='';
function setval(varval){
variavel=varval;
event.preventDefault();
$('#loadexternalfile').load(variavel);
return;
}
</script>

<button><a onclick="javascript:setval('test1.txt')" />teste 1</a></button>
<button><a onclick="javascript:setval('test2.txt')" />teste 2</a></button>

<div id="loadexternalfile"></div>
```